# How to apply partial validation in Django Models on a REST API

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm getting started with building REST API with Django using DRF. 
I get that there are default validations that can be applied to fields while definig a Model class.

I need to know, what should be a good approach for defing a partial validation for field.

Let us consider the following Model CLass :

```
class Test(models.Model):
   a = models.CharField("A", max_length=100)    
   b = models.TextField("B", blank=True, null=True)
   c = models.TextField("C", null=True, blank=True)
```

Now for field **a** it is a required field which is what I need, for the fields **b** and **c**, I want that either of one should be present always, that is if b is present c can be null or empty and vice-a-versa.

So I read that I can write the serializer and wireup the validation code within it, also I can define a **clean** method within my model to provide the validation logic.

Can someone provide me an example?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [validate](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#validation) Method:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    def validate(self, data):            
        if data.get('c') or data.get('b'):
            return data
        raise serializers.ValidationError("Provide B or C")
```

Answer (score 0):

serializer have the get fields method where you can do the operations

```
class Test(serializer.Srailizers):
   a = serializer.CharField()    
   b = serializer.TextField()
   c = serializer.TextField()

   def get_fields(self):
      fields = super().get_fields()
      # check you logic here and make change
      fields['b'].required = False
      return fields
```